Proving that restriction of $\sigma$-algebra is a $\sigma$-algebra
Let $X$ be a set and $\Sigma$ be a $\sigma$-algebra of $X$. Show that $\Sigma \cap A = \{E \cap A: E \in \Sigma \}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra of $X$
My attempt actually showed that this is impossible:
Suppose $F \in \Sigma \cap A$ and that $\Sigma \cap A$ is a $\sigma$-algebra of $X$, then $F = E \cap A$ for some $E \in \Sigma$. Since $\Sigma \cap A$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, we have that $F^c \in \Sigma \cap A$, but that means $F^c=E^c \cup A^c=G \cap A$, for some $G \in \Sigma$. Thus: $A^c \subset E^c \cup A^c \subset G \cap A \subset A$, which is impossible.
Could you guys help me find my mistake? Thank you

Obviously $\Sigma \cap A$ cannot be a $\sigma$ algebra on $X$. It is a $\sigma$ algebra on $A$.

As it has been pointed out in an earlier comment, $\Sigma \cap A$ is not a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$, but on $A$. Your observation, then, shows either that $\Sigma \cap A$ is not a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ or that the family of sets $\Sigma \cap A$ is not closed under relative complements with respect to $X$. However, this closure is not necessary for $\Sigma \cap A$ to be a $\sigma$-algebra (on $A$). Indeed, unless $A$ is identical to $X$, that situation will never occur (consider that $\emptyset$ is an element of $\Sigma \cap A$).
Remember that when we are talking about a $\sigma$-algebra, we are implicitly referring to a set on which such $\sigma$-algebra is defined, and it is important to specify that set.

Notice that $\Sigma \cap A$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on X is a contradiction whenever $A \subsetneq X$. Since $X \in \Sigma \cap A \implies \exists E\in \Sigma$ such that $X=E \cap A$. This is a contradiction since $E \cap A \subsetneq X$.
